# Connect to the same database WordPress tables are added to

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress, pdo

I'm developing a custom WordPress theme and I want to fetch some date from the database that I used to install WordPress.

The data I want to fetch is not the website posts, It's custom data.

That data is stored in a table inside the same Database that WordPress is installed on, So in that Database there are the following tables (`custom_table`, `wp-posts`, `wp-users`, `wp-settings`, ..Etc Etc).

So I'm wondering if WordPress has some functions or files to connect to that database.

I can create a custom PHP file and connect to the Database, Then include that file to the files where I want to fetch the data.

But I want to see if there is a better way.

Also if these features exist in WordPress, Does it use specific database connection functions like `mysql_connect`, `mysqli_connect` or PDO?

Comment: I googled for "wordpress php database access" and these links popped up: [Class Reference/wpdb](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb),  [How To Make Connection To WordPress Data Base In A Plugin?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/162614/how-to-make-connection-to-wordpress-data-base-in-a-plugin), [WordPress: Access Database From Widget Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17373086/wordpress-access-database-from-widget-code) and many, many more.

Answer (score 1):

'$wpdb' is a global database connection variable in WordPress. The simplest example of db selection operation in WordPress is this:

```
$wpdb->get_results( 
    "SELECT ID, post_title 
    FROM $wpdb->posts
    WHERE post_status = 'draft'"
);
```

You can obviously learn more about the database operations in wp from the [WPDB codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) entry.